# Lightning component not re-executed when related child records are inserted

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I have included a lightning component in opportunity flexi page under detail tab which will check if there are any child records with specific status(ex:status__c=='a') and shows some progress bar.

Initially if the opportunity contains no related child and hence progress bar is empty. But I navigate to related tab(standard) and add a child record with status__c=='a', child record is created(all as a single page application without any page reloads). But now if I just click on detail tab, still my progress bar component is empty but if I refresh the page, then progress bar is shown. Is there something we could do here?

Comment: I don't see any event for which you can listen to whenever a child record is created so that you could refresh your component. As of now only solution I can think of is creating custom component for creating new child record and firing event which your other component will listen to. Unfortunately lot of custom code.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to listen for either [force:recordSaveSuccess](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_recordSaveSuccess.htm) or [force:refreshView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_refreshView.htm) events in order to determine if you need to refresh the data from the server.